# "Undefined variable: books

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-4, eloquent

I'm getting this error:

> "Undefined variable: books (View:
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\Shop\resources\views\welcome.blade.php)"

I'm having trouble displaying my items in my `Welcome.blade.php` because it says that I have an undefined variable. And I can't find a way to make it work.

This is my **Model**

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Product extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'description',
        'condition',
        'category_id',
        'image'
    ];

    public function category()
    {
        $this->belongsTo(Category::class);
    }
}
```

This is my **ProductsController**

```
 namespace App\Http\Controllers;

 use Illuminate\Http\Request;
 use App\Category;
 use App\Product;

class ProductsController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $products = Product::all();
        return view('admin.product.index',compact('products'));
    }

    public function create()
    {
        $categories = Category::pluck('name','id');
        return view ('admin.product.create', compact('categories'));
    }


    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $product = $request->except('image');

        //validation
        $this->validate($request,[
            'name' => 'required',
            'condition' => 'required',
            'image' => 'image|mimes:png,jpg,jpeg|max:10000'
        ]);


        //image upload
        $image = $request->image;
        if( $image ){
            $imageName=$image->getClientOriginalName();
            $image->move('images',$imageName);
            $product['image']=$imageName;
        }

        Product::create($product);
        return redirect()->route('admin.index');
    }
}
```

This is my **Welcome.blade.php**

```
<div class="row">
    @forelse( $books as $book)
        <div class="column-prod">
            <a href="{{route('book')}}">
                <div class="card-prod">
                    <center>
                        <img src="/css/aa.jpg"  style="width: 300px; height: 300px;">
                    </center> 
            </a>
            <div class="container-prod">
                <h2></h2>
                <p class="title">{{$book->name}}</p>
                <p class="price">Php 450.00</p>

                <p>
                    <button class="button">
                        <i class="fas fa-cart-arrow-down"></i>Add to Cart
                    </button>
                </p>

                <p>
                    <button class="button">
                        <i class="fas fa-heart"></i>  Add to Wishlist
                    </button>
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    @empty
         <h3> No Books </h3>
    @endforelse

</div> <!--Div all end-->
@endsection
```

This is my `web.php`, So sorry I'm new to this... I hope you can help me.

```
<?php
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Route::get('/cart','ShopController@cart');

Route::get('/signin','ShopController@signin');

Route::get('/book','ShopController@book');

Route::get('/wishlist','ShopController@wish');



Auth::routes();

Route::get('/logout', 'Auth\LoginController@logout');

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index');

Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin', 'middleware' => 'auth'], function(){
    Route::get('/',function(){
        return view('admin.index');
    })->name('admin.index');


    Route::resource('product','ProductsController');
    Route::resource('category','CategoriesController');
});
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. What is returning the `welcome` view?

Comment: Just an FYI, but it looks like you've got a closing div tag in the wrong place.

Comment: it returns error  ... "Undefined variable: books (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\Shop\resources\views\welcome.blade.php)"

it should display the name and picture of my added product

Comment: @Messi show us the content of the `./routes/web.php` file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

```
Route::get('/', function () {
return view('welcome');
});
```

with

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome')->with(['books' => \App\Product::all()]);
});
```

Comment: @Messi If it solve your problem then make it as accepted answer so that others can find it useful. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
Route::get('/', function () {
return view('welcome');
});
```

With

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome')->with(['books' => \App\Books::all()]);
});
```

(if this works, then you should move the code into the controller like you did with the rest)

Comment: undefined `books`

Comment: this will still throw the same error as you are passing `products` but the view is looking for `$books`